# Elementwise power operation using CUDA Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

Is there a way of transforming a thrust vector with a `pow` function? In other words, I want to transform each element `x` of a vector to `pow(x,a)`, with `a` a constant.

Comment: you could write your own functor to do this

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [Section Transformations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#topic_4_1) in Thrust Quict Start Guide for how to write a functor with initialized parameters.

```
struct saxpy_functor
{
    const float a;

    saxpy_functor(float _a) : a(_a) {}

    __host__ __device__
        float operator()(const float& x, const float& y) const { 
            return a * x + y;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example. As @Eric has mentioned, all what is needed is defining your own power functor and using `thrust::transform`.

```
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

class power_functor {

    double a;

    public:

        power_functor(double a_) { a = a_; }

        __host__ __device__ double operator()(double x) const 
        {
            return pow(x,a);
        }
};

void main() {

    int N = 20;

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_n(N);
    thrust::sequence(d_n.begin(), d_n.end());

    thrust::transform(d_n.begin(),d_n.end(),d_n.begin(),power_functor(2.));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        double val = d_n[i];
        printf("Device vector element number %i equal to %f\n",i,val);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Is it on on purpose that the method `operator()` returns `int` rather than `double`?

Comment: @SomethingSomething It was a mistake. Fixed. Thank you for notifying me.